# Same mongodb query gives different explain plan

Tags: mongodb, performance, query-planner

I have two mongo queries, the only change in a query is merchantId field still both queries giving me different winning plan.

First Query

```
db.transactions.find({"created":{"$gte":1527465600000,"$lte":1527551999000},"merchantId":940,"additionalInformation.REQUESTOR":{"$ne":"MOTO"},"$or":[{"paymentMode":{"$ne":"UPI"}},{"bankCode":{"$ne":"GTEZ"}}]}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(200).explain()
```

Output of above query

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "$or" : [
                                            {
                                                    "$not" : {
                                                            "bankCode" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : "GTEZ"
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "$not" : {
                                                            "paymentMode" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : "UPI"
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                    "merchantId" : {
                                            "$eq" : 940
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "created" : {
                                            "$lte" : 1527551999000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "created" : {
                                            "$gte" : 1527465600000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "$not" : {
                                            "additionalInformation.REQUESTOR" : {
                                                    "$eq" : "MOTO"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "sortPattern" : {
                            "_id" : -1
                    },
                    "limitAmount" : 200,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "filter" : {
                                            "$and" : [
                                                    {
                                                            "$or" : [
                                                                    {
                                                                            "$not" : {
                                                                                    "bankCode" : {
                                                                                            "$eq" : "GTEZ"
                                                                                    }
                                                                            }
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                            "$not" : {
                                                                                    "paymentMode" : {
                                                                                            "$eq" : "UPI"
                                                                                    }
                                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                                            ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                            "$not" : {
                                                                    "additionalInformation.REQUESTOR" : {
                                                                            "$eq" : "MOTO"
                                                                    }
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "created" : 1,
                                                    "merchantId" : 1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "created_1_merchantId_1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "isUnique" : false,
                                            "isSparse" : false,
                                            "isPartial" : false,
                                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "created" : [
                                                            "[1527465600000.0, 1527551999000.0]"
                                                    ],
                                                    "merchantId" : [
                                                            "[940.0, 940.0]"
                                                    ]
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

    },
    "serverInfo" : {

    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

Second Query

```
db.transactions.find({"created":{"$gte":1527465600000,"$lte":1527551999000},"merchantId":1429,"additionalInformation.REQUESTOR":{"$ne":"MOTO"},"$or":[{"paymentMode":{"$ne":"UPI"}},{"bankCode":{"$ne":"GTEZ"}}]}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(200).explain()
```

Output of above query

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "$or" : [
                                            {
                                                    "$not" : {
                                                            "bankCode" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : "GTEZ"
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "$not" : {
                                                            "paymentMode" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : "UPI"
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            },
                            {
                                    "merchantId" : {
                                            "$eq" : 1429
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "created" : {
                                            "$lte" : 1527551999000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "created" : {
                                            "$gte" : 1527465600000
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "$not" : {
                                            "additionalInformation.REQUESTOR" : {
                                                    "$eq" : "MOTO"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "LIMIT",
                    "limitAmount" : 200,
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                    "$and" : [
                                            {
                                                    "$or" : [
                                                            {
                                                                    "$not" : {
                                                                            "bankCode" : {
                                                                                    "$eq" : "GTEZ"
                                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                    "$not" : {
                                                                            "paymentMode" : {
                                                                                    "$eq" : "UPI"
                                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                                            }
                                                    ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "merchantId" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 1429
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "created" : {
                                                            "$lte" : 1527551999000
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "created" : {
                                                            "$gte" : 1527465600000
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                    "$not" : {
                                                            "additionalInformation.REQUESTOR" : {
                                                                    "$eq" : "MOTO"
                                                            }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    ]
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                            "_id" : 1
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "_id_",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "isUnique" : true,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                                    "direction" : "backward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "_id" : [
                                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }

    },
    "serverInfo" : {

    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

As you can see only param difference is merchantId, still explain gives different winning plan also IXSCAN also shows different indexes used. In first query **created_1_merchantId_1** index is used and in second query ***id*** index is used. First query takes 40 seconds to get results while second query gives 1 sec. Quick will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're sorting on `_id`. That's why it gets taken into consideration. It clearly works better and why it is chosen. It would seem more likely the "two same" queries actually differ wildly in the amount of data they actually select. You need to look at the `transactions.explain("executionStats").find(..` output to see more of the detail

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/ may shed some light. [Hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint) the index to see if it gives you the expected performance.

Comment: @NeilLunn but why indexes used in both queries are different? even if on parameter difference in a query is merchantId?